# Problem inserting database row using last row in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, insert-update

I'd like to be able to do the following initially and also at anytime.

```sql
insert into balance (closing_amount, opening_amount, created, tx_id)

select closing_amount + :value, closing_amount, :date, :tx_id from balance order by id desc limit 1
```

Basically I'm inserting by using previous values. But if there are no values to begin with, nothing gets inserted.

I could use a union to which works the first time but duplicates on subsequent inserts.

I want to avoid two trips. Is there a way to do this?

Also, the tx_id will always be unique.

Comment: "_I want to avoid two trips_" Just to note in passing that because SQLite is a locally-linked database engine, avoiding multiple "trips" is (generally) far less important than when using a client-server database. (Having said that, I've just finished tweaking some multi-level views so I can do "_everything in one call_" !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
insert into balance (closing_amount, opening_amount, created, tx_id)
select coalesce(max(closing_amount), 0) + :value, 
       coalesce(max(closing_amount), 0), 
       :date, 
       :tx_id 
from (       
  select closing_amount 
  from balance 
  order by tx_id desc
  limit 1
) t;
```

You only need the last `closing_amount`, so `max(closing_amount)` from the subquery, which returns 1 row or none at all, will return that `closing_amount` or `null` respectively.

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6SwQrB7Cjqozazk8WoKfDX/1).